# Node.js(Express.js + Sequelize.js ORM): Why does query not work with quoted table name?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

Есть приложение на основе Express. База данных - postgresql, ORM - Sequelize. Это обработчик POST-запроса, в котором мне нужно получить пользователя из базы по username.

I have an app based on express.js with postgresql and sequelize.js as ORM. Here is POST query handler where I need to get user from database by 'username' field:

```
// /routes/login.js
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  models.User.findAll({ 
    where: { 
      username:req.body.username 
    } 
  }).then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  });
  res.render('login');
});
```

Logs:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."username" = 'admin';
[]
```

If I try this query in psql from command line, but without quotes around Users

```
SELECT "id", "username", "password" FROM Users AS "User" WHERE "User"."username" = 'admin';
```

It works properly and return 1 row.

Connection from app to DB is ok.

What's wrong with query generated by Sequelize? May I turn off quoting or should I make some additional setup of my database?

Answer (score 0):

Query generated by ORM is ok, quotes are needed for exact definition of table name, for saying that the name is "Users", not "users". In my case I had both "users" and "Users" tables created. Query without quotes worked, because it used "users" table instead, where a user was added. "Users" table was empty.